# How to link a Social Media account using Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm using Laravel Socialite to let the user login using fb, twitter or google which works well. But, there's part of the application that allows the user to link its other social account if they also want to use them when logging in, in short multiple sign in options for a single account. My problem now is, I don't know how to attain since I really don't have idea and I can't find some guide in the internet. I have tried re-using the callback function but it is not even getting inside the function. Here's what I have tried:

```
 public function linkMedia(Request $request, SocialMedia $social)
 {
    $provider = $request->route('provider');


    return Socialite::driver($provider)->with(['type' => "link"])->redirect();
}

//callback function with my sign up with social media
public function handleProviderCallback(Social $service, $provider)
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/')->withErrors([__('names.generalError')]);
    }
    dd($user);
}
```

If you have some suggestions or resources for tutorials, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help. Been stuck for 2 days now.

Comment: You can check these https://github.com/ankurk91/laravel-socialite-multiple-providers-example and https://packagist.org/packages/ipunkt/laravel-socialite-profiles and how they are done. It lets you add multiple providers login to a single profile.

Comment: @CritingZ I think it provides multiple log in only. I already have multiple log in option, what I want is in their profile (when they're already logged in), they can add an additional log in option.

Comment: Yes, the second one does exactly that "Socialite profiles extends the Laravel Socialite package by allowing multiple social network profiles being attached at the user. Attaching and detaching can be done after being logged in." You can add additional profiles/logins after you are logged in already